# Pre-trained vector of skip-gram and skip-n-gram

Tags: word2vec, pre-trained-model

I am doing a project where I need a pre-trained vector of the skip-gram model. I heard that there is also a variant named skip-n-gram model which gives better result.

I am wondering what do I need to train the models myself? Since I just need them to initialize the embedding layer for my model.

I have searched enough but didn't get good examples. I need suggestion from you. Where can I get such pre-trained model or there is no pre-trained model for this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can train our own word-vectors if you have enough data with you. This can be done using [gensim](https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/index.html). They provide very simple yet powerful APIs for topic modeling.

But if you want to use already trained word2vec models, you can use the [word2vec model](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7XkCwpI5KDYNlNUTTlSS21pQmM/edit?usp=sharing)  released by Google. It’s 1.5GB and includes word vectors for a vocabulary of 3 million words and phrases that they trained on roughly 100 billion words from a Google News dataset.

You can load this model with the gensim. Download the trained word2vec model and use following code to get started.

```
import math
import sys
import gensim
import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings(action='ignore', category=UserWarning, module='gensim') 

from gensim.models.keyedvectors import KeyedVectors

words = ['access', 'aeroway', 'airport']

# load the model
model = KeyedVectors.load_word2vec_format(path_to_model, binary=True)

# to extract word vector
print(model[words[0]])  # vector representing access
```

Result vector:

```
[ -8.74023438e-02  -1.86523438e-01 .. ]
```

Please note that your system may freeze while loading of such huge model.

Comment: No @MSaifulBari I don't have much idea. But I would suggest you look at [fasttext](https://fasttext.cc) once. I think they have implemented n-gram models.

Comment: @Digao each word is translated into an n-dimensional embedding vector where each row can be understood as a feature. Similar (or semantically similar) words will have these features very near to each other. You can find this out by calculating the cosine similarity between different word vectors.

Comment: @Harman but how about the columns of this vector ? Is the number of columns the same number as the words in the training ( in this case 100 billion ) ? I mean, does the first number in this vector (-8.74023438e-02) refer to the probability of the first word in the training to belong to the skip-gram ?

Comment: @Digao each word embedding is a vector of size 300*1. Hence, it will just have feature information for that particular word. here, (-8.74023438e-02)  doesn't refer to the probability, it's one of the 300  features. This is a good [tutorial](http://mccormickml.com/2016/04/19/word2vec-tutorial-the-skip-gram-model/) to look at if you're interested.

Comment: according to the link you sent, the vector would be 1*300, not 300*1, right. And the vector @MSaifulBari is looking for is the middle layer of the network right ?